# Nested REST routes and subnamespaces in CakePHP3

Tags: rest, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3 the rest routing doesn't call classes in subnamespace. For example the route "posts/2/comments/10" call App\Controller\CommentsController. I want it to call App\Controller\Posts\CommentsController because comments are not always for posts...

Here is my solution :

```
    $routes->resources('Posts');  
Router::scope('/posts/:post_id/',['post_id'=>'[0-9]+','prefix'=>'posts'], function($routes){
    $routes->resources('Comments');
});
```

It works fine but i don't know if it is a good practice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group controllers by namespace use `Router::prefix()` or `$routes->prefix()` instead of `$routes->scope()`